# How do I write this if condition with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my function atm:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#knd").click(function() {
    $("#wars").animate({
        opacity:'1'
    }); 


}); 

});
```

It works great but I want to add the option to remove the box with another click, figured I'd do it with an if statement but I'm not 100% on the syntax in Jquery. I want something along the lines of:

```
if(#wars is visible) {

$("#wars").animate({
         opacity:'0'
    });
```

How would I write the if statement for this?

SOLUTION:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#knd").click(function() {
if($("#wars").css('opacity') === '0') {         
    $("#wars").animate({
    opacity:'1'
    }); //end of animate
}


else {
$("#wars").animate({
    opacity:'0'
});  //end of animate
}


}); //end of KND click function
}); //end of doc ready function
```

I had to change the visibility and set it to opacity instead, then it worked like a charm with the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check the following condition :

```
if($('#knd').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
    $("#wars").animate({
        opacity:'0'
    }); 
}
```

Suggested solution:

```
if($('#wars').css('opacity') === '0') {
    $("#wars").animate({
        opacity:'1'
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** along with **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector:

```
if($('#knd').is(':visible')) {
    $("#wars").animate({
        opacity:'0'
    }); 
}
```

Comment: this works but when it's visible it goes back to being invisible..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is(':visible')` but you can use `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()`.

`*Toggle()` function automatically does what you're intending to do, with **effects**.

Comment: toggle doesn't work at all for some reason..

Comment: You've to use `$('#wars').fadeToggle();`